# Autocompletebox - upper limits for item source records?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpftoolkit, itemssource

**This is all for the WPF Toolkit running on .NET 3.5**

What are the upper limits of the `ItemsSource` property that I can set for a WPF `AutocompleteBox`? I have played around with using simple strings and slightly more complex objects as the `ItemsSource` and there seems to be a performance degradation at about 1000 items. It becomes near unusable at anything above 2000 items (roughly). The items will load OK but when it comes to filtering it slows down quite a bit (using **Contains** for the item filter BTW).

Are there known upper limits for this? If so, what are other, better, ways to handle large records? I need to have `AutocompleteBox`es that handle 10,000+ items in the `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical limit, however, for performance and usability issues you should consider  limiting the results shown manually to a decent value, so the user experience stays smooth. Write a wrapper class and set it as `ItemsSource`. The class would in turn call your real data source but only provide limited number of results.

Comment: I would say no more than 50 results. Personally I would not show more than 5 results, since you can show those without having to scroll.